# python, matrix object calling

Tags: python, class, object, matrix, methods

maybe a bit trivial question but i'm having trouble calling the object.
How can I call an object from this class and possibly call the add method correctly?

sample code:

```
class MyMatrix:
    height = 0
    width = 0
    data = tuple()

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.height = len(data)
        self.width = len(data[0])
        self.data = data

    def add(mat1, mat2):
        if mat1.height != mat2.height or mat1.width != mat2.width:
            print("The matrices are not the same size!")
            return

        rows = []
        for i in range(len(mat1.data)):
            row = []
            for j in range(len(mat1.data[0])):
                row.append(mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j])

            rows.append(tuple(row))
        return MyMatrix(tuple(rows))
```

Thank you in advance for every answer.

Comment: `MyMatrix(data)`?

Comment: As an aside, why are you making `height`, `width` and `data` class variables that you *immediately and always* shadow in `__init__` with instance variables? Seems pointless.

Comment: @Niziol the question doesn't seem to show what's wrong / what you've tried that made you think it's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the methods like follows; for your code to work, however, you need to implement getitem (so that you can do matrix[1][2] e.g.).

```
class MyMatrix:
    height = 0
    width = 0
    data = tuple()

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.height = len(data)
        self.width = len(data[0])
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.data.__getitem__(item)

    def add(mat1, mat2):
        if mat1.height != mat2.height or mat1.width != mat2.width:
            print("The matrices are not the same size!")
            return

        rows = []
        for i in range(len(mat1.data)):
            row = []
            for j in range(len(mat1.data[0])):
                row.append(mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j])

            rows.append(tuple(row))
        return MyMatrix(tuple(rows))


m1 = MyMatrix([[1,2,3]])
m2 = MyMatrix([[3,2,1]])
m12 = m1.add(m2)
print(m12.data)
```